# How can I delete a task in an Android Studio from an arraylist and a listview?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapterview

I'm trying to build a to-do list in android studio but I don't quite get how to go about deleting one of the tasks already on the app.

As you can see in the code below, I'm using an arraylist to store tasks and add new ones and a list view to display the arraylist. Does anyone know how I could delete a task here? thank you in advance!

```
package com.example.todolist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainJava extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

     // 1. Some variables and definitions
        ListView listView;
        ArrayList<MyData> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyAdapter adapter;
        private EditText taskEntered;

     /* Define Menu item identifiers.
        Menu.FIRST is a constant of the Menu class used to define first menu item,
         used by convention
     */
     final int ADD = Menu.FIRST;
     final int DELETE = Menu.FIRST+ 1;
     final int UPDATE = Menu.FIRST+ 2;
     final int SAVE = Menu.FIRST+ 3;
     final int CLOSE = Menu.FIRST+ 4;


     // 2. Method: The classic ON CREATE
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // locate the widgets: edit text (to get string) and list view (to put string)
            taskEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterTask);
            listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

            // attach listener to list view
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            taskEntered.setText("");
        }

     // 3. Method: ON CREATE OPTIONS MENU
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuItem item1 = menu.add(0, ADD, Menu.NONE, "ADD");
         MenuItem item2 = menu.add(0, DELETE, Menu.NONE, "DELETE");
         MenuItem item3 = menu.add(0, UPDATE, Menu.NONE, "UPDATE");
         MenuItem item4 = menu.add(0, SAVE, Menu.NONE, "SAVE");
         MenuItem item5 = menu.add(0, CLOSE, Menu.NONE, "CLOSE");
         return true;
     }


     // 4. Method: ON OPTIONS SELECTED
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         int itemID = item.getItemId();  // get id of menu item picked

         switch (itemID) {

             case ADD :
                 addNewTask();   // prints entered task in list view
                 return true;

             case DELETE :
                 // not sure what to add here
                 deleteTask();
                 return true;

             case CLOSE : finish();  // close will be updated later

             default: super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
         return false;
     }


    // 5. Method: PRINT NEW TASK in list view and ADD NEW TASK to arrayList
     public void addNewTask() {
         // get string from the edit text
         String taskString = taskEntered.getText().toString();

         // create ArrayList values
         arrayList.add(new MyData(arrayList.size(), taskString));
         // TESTING: arrayList.add(new MyData(2, " Robert"));

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         taskEntered.setText("");  // clear edit text bar after adding item

     }

     // 6. Method: Listener, when you click on an item in list view it does this:

     // listener is passed into the position of the item that was clicked?

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            // you click on an item in list view
         String task = arrayList.get(position).getName();  // get name of task
         int numTask = arrayList.get(position).getNum();   // get number of task

         // set edit text field to show the item you just clicked
         taskEntered.setText(numTask + " " + task);
     }

     // 7. Method: Delete a task

     public void deleteTask() {
            
            //help here 
         
         
         // get string from the edit text
         String taskString = taskEntered.getText().toString();

         // create ArrayList values - how do i make it be a loop ??
         arrayList.remove();
         // TESTING: arrayList.add(new MyData(2, " Robert"));

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }


    }
```

Comment: Are you just having an issue removing something from an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure how to connect the listener and maybe the onclick so that the specific item in the listview that is clicked is removed from the arraylist and listview

Comment: When do you want the item to be deleted? You already have a listener set up for when an item is clicked so I presume you want it to trigger elsewhere?

Comment: Ideally, the item would be deleted when the "Delete" button in the options menu is clicked!

Comment: But there's only one options menu? So which item in the list would be deleted?

Comment: so the steps for the user would be: 1. click on an already-filled line in the listview, 2. the task in that line is displayed in the edit text widget, 3. click on delete in the options menu, 4. the button delete deletes the specific line the user had just clicked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229909/discussion-between-henry-twist-and-someonelearning17).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this method that worked!

```
 // 7. Method: Delete a task

 public void deleteTask() {

     // remove the arrayList item in the position that was clicked
     arrayList.remove(itemPos);

     // loop through items and reassign numbers
     for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
         arrayList.get(i).setNum(i+1);
     }

     //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
     adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     taskEntered.setText("");
 }
```

For this to work I had to update the onItemClick method to keep track of the position of the item selected (Within the arraylist). Once I had the position of the item I could just use arrayList.remove(itemPos) to delete it.

Comment: I know you maybe start learning android but there's a better way for implementing lists i really recommend you study it. It resolves many problems of Listview it called <b>RecyclerView</b>